# Why did BiBi change their center in their live shows for the song Love Novels?

Tags: love-live

According to [Wikia](http://love-live.wikia.com/wiki/Love_Novels), the original Love Novels has Ayase Eri as the center, but it was replaced by Nico in the live shows.

[image: Love Novels Wikia Screenshot]

Has it been disclosed why this was the case? What is the reason behind the change?

Comment: I am not aware Eli ever was center for that song, and the only place that mentions it is the wikia you are talking about. After searching JP pages, I don't see anything about it either (it always has been Nico as far as I know). Do you know if there are any other references?

Comment: Kind of agree with Jimmy's comment. Even [the PV for School Festival Arcade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwEK9sy2oxo) shows Nico as the center. You may want to reconfirm this on their [talk](http://love-live.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Love_Novels) page, though.

Comment: Anyway, [this is the comment from the editor who made that statement](http://love-live.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:19126#2): "so for sweet&sweet holiday, love novels, and shiranai love*oshiete love, they switched some parts for the concerts to make Kotori, Nozomi, and Nico the centers of those songs.".